# hypersurface of degree d Hilbert polynomial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, hilbert-schemes

I am in trouble to solve part (2) Exercise 1.13 from "Moduli of Curves"
by Harris and Morrison on page 9:

**Exercise (1.13)**
2) Fix a subscheme $X \subset \mathbb{P}^r$. Show, by taking cohomology
of the exact sequence of $X \subset \mathbb{P}^r$, that $X$ is a hypersurface of degree $d$ if and only it's Hilbert polynomial is.

$P_X(m)= \binom{r+ m}{m}- \binom{r+m-d}{m-d}$.

One direction is trivial: If $X$ is hypersurface of degree
$d$ defined by polynomial $f$ of degree $d$ then the sequence
$0 \to O_{\mathbb{P}^r}(-d) \to O_{\mathbb{P}^r} \to O_X \to 0$ does the job.

Another direction is more complicated: let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^r$ with
Hilbert $P_X(m)$. It's degree is $r-1$ thus $\dim \ X=r-1$.

Let us decompose $X= M_1 \cup ... M_s \cup D_1 \cup ... \cup D_t$
with $\dim \ M_i=r-1$ and $\dim D_j <r-1$. Every $M_i$ is a hyperplane
of degree $d_i$ and the **main problem is to show that $s=1$**, ie
$X$ has only one component of dimension $r-1$.

Because: assume we know $s=1$. Then $P_{M_1} + P_{\bigcup_j D_j}
= P_X +P_{M_1 \cap (\bigcup_j D_j)}$, so $deg(M_1)= deg(X)$ and
therefore $M_1$ is a hypersurface of degree $d$ and thus $P_{M_1}=P_X$.

The decomposition $X= M_1 \cup \bigcup_j D_j$ induces an exact sequence

$$0 \to I_{\bigcup_j D_j}/I_X \to O_X \to O_{M_1} \to 0$$

The Hilbert polynomial is additive wrt exact sequences and we obtain
$P_{I_{\bigcup_j D_j}/I_X}=0$, so $X=M_1$.

But I don't know how to show that $s=1$, ie that $X$ has only one
irreducible component of dimension $r-1$.

**Addendum**:  Essentially my question reduces to following problem: Let $X= M_1 \cup ... \cup M_s \subset \mathbb{P}^r$ a purely $r-1$-dimensional subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^r$ (ie every irreducible component $M_i$ of $X$ has dimension $r-1$) with Hilbert polynomial $P_X(m)= \binom{r+ m}{m}- \binom{r+m-d}{m-d}= \binom{r+ m}{r}-\binom{r+m-d}{r}$. And we have to show that $X$ is irreducible, ie $s=1$. We observe that every $r-1$-dimensional subscheme $M_i$ is a hyperplane of degree $d_i$ and by additivity of the Hilbert polynomial we obtain $d= \sum_i d_i ^s$. But I don't know how to continue from here to prove the claim...

Comment: If $M_i$'s are hypersurfaces of degree $d_i$, then their union is a hypersurface of degree $\sum d_i$. So, can't you always take $s=1$?

Comment: @Mohan: I don't think that it's obvious here. Doing similar argument (namely split the Hilbert polynomial into union of dimension $r-1$ components $M_i$ and lower dimension components) as before then $M_i$ are hypersurfaces of degrees $d_i$ then again a degree comparison gives just $d= \sum_i^s d_i$. So why can it eg happen that $s=5$ with $\sum_i ^5  d_i=d$?  or in other words that $X$ has $5$ irreducible components of of dimension $r-1$? That's exactly the crucial part

Comment: or did I maybe misread your argument?

Comment: @Mohan: Essentially my question reduced to following problem: Let $X= M_1 \cup ... \cup M_s \subset \mathbb{P}^r$ a purely $r-1$-dimensional subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^r$ with Hilbert polynomial $P_X(m)= \binom{r+ m}{m}- \binom{r+m-d}{m-d}= \binom{r+ m}{r}-\binom{r+m-d}{r}$. Show that then $X$ is irreducible, ie $s=1$. We observe that every $r-1$-dimensional subscheme $M_i$ is a hyperplane of degree $d_i$ and by additivity of Hilbert polynomials we obtain $d= \sum_i d_i ^s$. And what to do next?

Comment: Why do you think $X$ would have to be irreducible? I don’t see where that idea is coming from. In the “easy” direction you use the degree of the hypersurface, but you don’t use irreducibility.

Comment: @ZachTeitler: That's exactly the claim in the exercise I have quoted above. I have to **show** that if I have a  subscheme $X \subset \mathbb{P}^r$ with the Hilbert polynomial given above, then $X$ is a degree $d$ hypersurface (ie irreducible).  And in the “easy” direction you are right: I only use the assumption that $X=V(f)$ for homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$.

Comment: A "hypersurface" is not necessarily irreducible; $V(xy)$ is a hypersurface, it is reducible. Plus: you are trying to prove something that is not true. Having the given Hilbert polynomial *does not* imply that the hypersurface is irreducible. I think you are supposed to prove that with the given Hilbert polynomial, the variety is a degree $d$ hypersurface (ie., defined by a single equation); but it can be reducible (the defining equation might factor as a product). You can't prove it's irreducible because that's not necessarily true (with only information of Hilbert polynomial).

Comment: @ZachTeitler: Yes I think I see my thinking error. I indeed wrongly assumed that hypersurface has to irreducible. So a hypersurface of $\mathbb{P}^r$ is by definition a closed subscheme of the structure $V(f)$ with homogeneous polynomial $f \in k[x_0,...,x_r]$. And of course as you said $f$ can be reducible and thus $X$ as well. On the other hand is it true (and why) that if $X \subset \mathbb{P}^r$ is irreducible subscheme of dimension $r-1$ then it has structure $X=V(f)$ for $f$ homogeneous polynomial?

Comment: (On phone, sorry for terseness) https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2638397